# Datatable loaded with Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 has higher precision than Excel workbook

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am uploading a currency rate workbook through a `filehandler` in VB.net through `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection`.

When viewing the rates in the Excel sheet, I see `0.55865921787709500000`.
Viewing the same rate in the datatable under debug mode, I see `0.55865921787709480000`.

Under Excel, the decimal places are set to `20` - seems to just pad out zeroes past decimal position 15.

I've tried reading/writing the cells to a text file (same '500000' result).
Tried saving the workbook as a comma-delimted text file - same '500000' result.

The rate worksheet is created from another web site.  I have attempted to add a 16th digit to the worksheet, but it flips back to zero after I move off the cell.  I know Excel has a 16-digit precision limit.  In this case, it appears to be storing more.

Is there any way to peek at the actual stored value in the workbook - other than examining the datatable?

Comment: what do you have access to change?  could we see the code that you can change?

Comment: By design: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel

Comment: I can change the import code to truncate the extra digits.  I'm asking why Excel is choosing to store more than 15 significant digits and hiding #16 when you view the figures in Excel.  The datatable produced from the OLEdb read of the workbook shows 16 digits, workbook shows 15.

Comment: I ran the situation by a co-worker.  The original rate sheet is generated by Crystal Reports.  He was able to view the rate sheet under Google Docs and the extra digits were displayed.  To answer my own question, Excel is storing more than 15 significant digits depending on the application that created the Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is retaining more than 15 significant digits - depending on what system created the original Excel document.  In this case, the doc was produced by Crystal Reports.  The "extra" significant digits can be viewed using the OLEDB connection against the Excel spreadsheet or by viewing it through the Google Docs version of Excel.
In this particular case, I had to make the SQL-stored rates match the spreadsheet.  I converted each rate to a decimal and a string.  I used the string to locate the period in the rate and start counting consecutive zeroes that appear after the decimal.  This count was added to 15 as the number of digits on a system round of the decimal.  The rounded number matched the figures shown when viewing the information in Excel.